# Optional where clause dependent on function argument

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql, where-clause

Given this pseudo code

```
create or replace procedure my_test
( arg1 IN varchar2 )
begin

  select var1, var2, var3 from table1

  where 
    var1 in (select var1 from table2)

  if(arg1 = 'some_val')
    and
    var2 < 100
  end if;
end;
```

Now, I know that `if` statements aren't permitted in `where` clauses, and all the examples of `case` statements I've seen only do variable assignment (rather than executing a clause) (e.g. [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793938/how-to-correctly-use-case-in-where-clause) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/oracle-sql-case-in-a-where-clause)).

Is it possible to filter against a where clause conditionally dependent on the argument function at all using a `case`, or is the only way to use dynamic SQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert you pseudo-code to SQL logic easily:

```
select var1, var2, var3
from table1
where var1 in (select var1 from table2) and
      ((arg1 = 'some_val' and var2 < 100) or
       (arg1 <> 'some_val')
      );
```

Note:  you need to be careful with `NULL` values.

And, this can be simplified to:

```
where var1 in (select var1 from table2) and
      (var2 < 100 or arg1 <> 'some_val')
```

Also, it is a good idea to prefix variables with something so they are not confused with column names.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to get my head around the logic there... in the first snippet I assume it's not safe to remove `arg1<> 'some_val'` because the second clause has to have something that returns true for the whole where clause to be executed?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you should be able to do this just with `and` and `or` conditions.

```
where var1 in (select var1 from table2)
  and ((arg1 = 'some_val' and var2 < 100) or
       arg1 != 'some_val')
```

Of course, a procedure can't just do a naked `select` like this.  You'd need to store the result somewhere, open a `sys_refcursor`, etc.

Comment: I actually am returning a `sys_refcursor` in the code I've got - I just wanted a minimal example here tho!

Answer (score 1):

You could emulate this behavior with the logical `or` operator:

```
SELECT var1, var2, var3
FROM   table1
WHERE  var1 IN (SELECT var1 FROM table2) AND
       (arg1 != 'some_val' OR var2 < 100)
```